# Does analytic closed-form solution exist

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, rational-functions

I have a polynomial (degree 6) that is form by multiplication of two smaller polynomials (degree 4 and 2)

$H(x) = 1+ax+bx^2+cx^3+dx^4)(u+vx+x^2) = \\u+ (a u+v)x + (a v+b u+1) x^2 + (a+b v+c u)x^3 +(b+c v+d u)x^4+(c+d v)x^5+ d x^6$

My goal so far has been to try and find out if an analytic expression for the  coefficients of the two smaller polynomials $(a,b,c,d,u,v)$ can be found given that I know the coefficients in the normalized polynomial

$H(x)/u = 1+ (a+v/u)x + (a v/u+b+1/u) x^2 + (a/u+bv/u+c)x^3 +(b/u+cv/u+d)x^4+(c/u+dv/u)x^5+ d/u x^6$

The coefficients are given by the following expressions

$
d/u = \frac{(W+1)^3-B^3}{(W+1)^3 + B^3} \\
c/u+dv/u = \frac{6(W-1)(W+1)^2}{(W+1)^3+B^3} \\
b/u+cv/u+d = \frac{3 (5 W^3-W^2-W+5)+3B^3}{(W+1)^3+B^3} \\
a/u+bv/u+c = \frac{4 (5 W^3-3 W^2+3 W-5)}{(W+1)^3+B^3} \\
a v/u+b+1/u = \frac{3 (5 W^3-W^2-W+5)-3B^3}{(W+1)^3+B^3} \\
a+v/u = \frac{6(W-1)(W+1)^2}{(W+1)^3+B^3}
$

where $W$ and $B$ are constants.
Note that the expressions for the coefficients of the $x$ and $x^5$ terms are equal. Don't know if this is useful but if the symmetric polynomial, formed by subtracting a 'left-right flipped' normalized polynomial from itself, can be put on the form $-2B^3(x^2-1)^3$.

I will accept any answer that provides the slightest clue to how I can make some progress on this problem. I have tried using the Wolfram-alpha website but it complained about input being to long and I never found out how to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

Any polynomial with real coefficients factors as a single constant times a product of some number of quadratic terms $x^2 + v x + u,$ times a number of linear terms $x - w.$ Furthermore, since each quadratic term is a pairing of complex roots $ (x -\lambda) ( x - \bar{\lambda})$ there is a sort of positivity built in to those, with your letters $u > 0$ and $u + v + 1 \geq 0$ may do it.

The problem I see is that there is no guarantee, having arranged each term to be monic, that you can fix the constant terms. That is, with your letters, I do not see how you can take
$$ e + a x + b x^2 + c x^3 + d x^4  $$
and guarantee that $e=1.$ So, any attempt to solve with $e=1$ is going to lead to gibberish or a dead end, as long as you are using letters.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning regarding the positivity. I understand that a complex conjugate pair of roots create a quadratic factor. Is it possible that you can explain the problem about the constant term on an even lower level. Maybe with a very simple example. Do you mean that there is an extra degree of freedom that is not accounted for? If I could just understand the implications of assuming $e=1$.

Comment: Try to solve your original problem with a letter such as my $e$ instead of $1.$ Things should improve.

Comment: I will give it a try but I don't see (at this point) how it can help because then I will have 7 unknowns (coefficients) but only 6 equations...

Comment: @niaren, the best version would be $e (x^2 + v x + u)(x^4 + a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d)$

Comment: I can't see how that $e$ helps. Considering the simplest case of $(1+ax)(b+x) = b + (ba+1)x + ax^2$ compared to $e(a+x)(b+x) = e(ab + (a+b)x + x^2)$. Then the normalized polynomials are $1+(a+1/b)x + (a/b)x^2$ and $(1 + \frac{a+b}{eab}x + \frac{1}{eab}x^2)$, respectively, and equating them to $1+ux+vx^2$ it seems that solving for a and b no form is more advantageous than the other. The e parameter makes no difference it seems. I know this case is so simple that it may not make sense to generalize to the problem in the post.

Comment: @niaren, the actual sensible thing is to have a monic quadratic times a monic quartic result in a monix sextic. Two unknowns plus four unknowns result in six unknowns; in your direction, you are saying the six are known.  $$  (x^2 + a x + b) (x^4 + c x^3 + d x^2 + e x + f) = (x^6 + g x^5 + h x^4 + i x^3 + j x^2 + k x + l ) $$

Comment: I assume you mean $(1+ax+bx^2)(1+cx+dx^2+ex^3+fx^4)$. However, I have tried to let Maple10 find the solution by using the solve function. Maple was not able to find a solution unfortunately. I then came to the conclusion that finding an analytic solution is either not possible or extremely difficult. However, I've just tried to find the solution using another approach and it seems that I'm able to solve the problem this way ;) I need to do some checking first to be absolutely sure.

Comment: @niaren, no, I meant  exactly what I wrote. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial

Answer (score 0):

By the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem), general polynomials of fifth degree or more (your is sixth) can't be solved by radicals. Your decomposition into a quadratic and a biquadratic factor, if given by "nice analytic formulas for the coefficients" (presumably you mean expressible by radicals) would give a solution in radicals for the general sixth degree equation (quadratics yield to the quadratic formula, biquadratics are solved by Ferrari's formula). So the answer is that this can't be done in general.

For polynomials with integral coefficients, with factors whose coefficients are again integers, there are reasonably efficient algorithms to find all factors, ask your favourite computer algebra system, or check [factoring of polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials). Some polynomials of particular forms (for example palindromic ones, or those with only even powers) can be solved, however. Sometimes the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) helps.